# NSlog showing odd output

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nslog

I have a NSlog that is giving odd output in the debugger. How do I get it to show the proper value?

```
 NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *data;

[self setStatus:@"Syncing data..."];
self.userInfo = [self.cloud Authenticate:[self serialNumber]];

if ( self.deviceInfo )
{
    data = [self.device GetData:&error];
    if ( !data )
    {
        [self displayErrorMessage:error];
        data = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    //data received from device: Log point
    NSLog(@"data received from device: %@",data);
```

Debuger output

```
   "<DataPoint: 0x1001f81b0>",
"<DataPoint: 0x10012f5f0>",
"<DataPoint: 0x1001f7780>",
"<DataPoint: 0x1001f8780>",
```

Comment: Try this, if it works, `NSLog(@"data received from device: %@",[data description])`;

Comment: `-GetData:` is obviously returning an object of class DataPoint. Theres no 'problem' here, what exactly do you expect?

Comment: What is improper about the value? It would appear that you are receiving an array of DataPoint objects from your `GetData:` method, and that's what it's logging.

Comment: data isn't a array, and you get the address of whatever it is.

Comment: @HinataHyuga nope, NSLog automagically calls `-description` on an object.

Comment: Since it might not be immediately apparent, the commas would seem to indicate an array of DataPoints rather than one being returned, so I'm pretty sure there are actually parens on the lines before and after the log output in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default string returned by NSObject's description method, which just prints the pointer value. If you want to see the proper data printed, override description in your DataPoint class:

```
- (NSString*) description
{
    // Example:
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ivar1=%@ , ivar2=%@",ivar1, ivar2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stored an object of `DataPoint` in the array, correct output is shown.

If you want to see full value for each of them, then you need to use

```
for(DataPoint *dp in data){
   NSLog(@"%@",dp.property);//property should be your property name of DataPoint class.
}
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : I didn't read that comment. And I wonder is my answer not correct? or only overloading of `description` is required?

Comment: Overloading -description is preferred, but you answer is correct as well. I downvoted, then un-did my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Ramy's good suggestion to override `description`, I suggest extending, rather than replacing, like this:

```
- (NSString *)description {

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@: ivar1=%@, ivar2=%@",
        [super description], self.ivar1, self.ivar2];
}
```

The inherited behavior that answers the class and the %p pointer is very useful, too.

Comment: If you care about the class and the pointer value, you can just quite easily include those yourself rather than depend on the NSObject formatting.

Comment: Sure, but this is what inheritance is for.  The potentially non-NSObject superclass may have already added useful behavior, or it may someday add useful behavior.  Or the ancestry may someday change ...  One problem I don't see developers facing -- even experienced ones -- is _overuse_ of OO concepts.

Comment: Had to replace %@ with %hu in. I add this to my datapoint class?

Comment: Yes (as per Ramy suggestion) add to your DataPoint class.  The inherited method will return a string, so %@ is the right format descriptor for it.

Comment: @danh: Never been faced with overuse of OO concepts? I can tell you are not a Java developer.

Comment: :-) I don't like to brag, but I know how to write slow, wasteful code in a wide variety of languages.